# Subversion 'Not a working copy' error

Tags: svn

I have just installed Subversion for Windows and have successfully checked out a copy of my plugin from the repository.  My understanding is that this would make a working copy -

```
c:\My Folder Path>svn co http://repository/folder "My folder"
```

The check out was successful and I received the message "Checked out revision 1101139."

Next I copied some files in to the working copy and attempted to check it in -

```
c:\My Folder Path>svn ci -m "Release of version 1.0"
```

My understanding was that this should ask me for my credentials and then merge my changes with the files already in the repository, but instead it instantly failed and displayed an error -

> svn: E155007: 'C:\My Folder Path' is not a working copy

Having used Google to search the problem, I deleted my working copy and started fresh, but this also failed with the same porblem.  Using `svn diff` also failed.

Can anybody please suggest what I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here was annoyingly simple.

I was starting in folder **c:\My Folder Path** and checking the files out to a sub-folder called **c:\My Folder Path\My folder**.

All I had to do was **cd "My folder""** to change the folder to **c:\My Folder Path\My folder** and the checkout worked fine.

Comment: Actually, you can use `svn co http://repo/folder .` (note the dot at the end, which means the current directory or, in other words, *here*) to checkout into the current directory, so `cd "My Folder Path" and then the above will work without the need to be two levels deep.